# Null values when I try to reach Rectangle

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a uwp project that i have a booking function in and would be pleased to have some help with one thing.

So i'm trying to reach a `Rectangle` in my `UserControl` from my `Main.xaml.cs` file, so i can set the `Rectangles` fill property.

This is how i have done it:

Method in `Main.xaml.cs` for finding the child property:

```
private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
        {
            int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
            for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
                FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
                // Not a framework element or is null
                if (fe == null) return null;

                if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
                {
                    // Found the control so return
                    return child;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Not found it - search children
                    DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
                    if (nextLevel != null)
                        return nextLevel;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Inside the function where i want to call the `Rectangle` that is named `StatusColor` I do this:

```
Rectangle Rec = FindChildControl<Rectangle>(GridView1, "StatusColor") as Rectangle;
```

But somehow when I try to execute the code I get this error for the variable `Rec`:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I know there are many posts about this exception but i still not getting any smarter by looking at them...

But as i said, I would be very pleased with someones help

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

My `xaml` in `Main.xaml` to declare the `UserControl`:

```
<GridView x:Name="GridView1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource testgrid}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Rooms}" Width="1740" Height="835" IsHitTestVisible="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="75,190,75,100" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Room">
                    <local:TemplateGrid x:Name="TemplateGrid"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

And this is how my code looks like for the `Rectangle`:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="StatusColor" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="218" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.901"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#CC17FF00" Offset="0"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
```

Comment: You are trying to search for control on a xaml page, yet you have pasted no xaml, should we just trust you and agree?

Comment: Sry, check the edit @TheGeneral

Answer (score 1):

It is these lines:

```
 // Not a framework element or is null
 if (fe == null) return null;
```

You are exiting the loop too early. When the element `i` is not a framework element, you should just ignore it and continue on to the next one.

So instead of exiting when you encounter a non-framework element, just execute the next lines only when it is one:

```
 if (fe != null)
 {
    // rest of checking
 }
```

or alternatively:

```
 if (fe == null) continue;
```

---

**EDIT**
A slight reworking of your code to:

```
    private T FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName) 
         where T: FrameworkElement
    {
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;

            // Not a framework element or is null
            if (fe == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
            {
                // Found the control so return
                return (T)child;
            }
            else
            {
                // Not found it - search children
                T nextLevel = this.FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
                if (nextLevel != null)
                {
                    return nextLevel;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

should be called with

```
Rectangle rec = FindChildControl<Rectangle>(GridView1, "StatusColor");
```

to give the correct result. At least it did in my test situation (with adjusted parameters).

The only real change was the use of `continue` instead of `return`. Furthermore I made use of generics to immediately return the correct type, no casting needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still getting the same error... Cant understand why though :(

Comment: Then it is back to option one: *debugging*. Step through this method examining the values returned and why. Don't forget to step *into* the recursive call.

Comment: `Rectangle Rec = FindChildControl<Rectangle>(GridView1, "StatusColor") as Rectangle;` Executes before the `for loop`. Right now i haven't got any clue why :(

Comment: Sorry to be such a pain in the as, but I still get the same error :(

Comment: Then you will need to step though the code *in your environment* and inspect what happens. Put a breakpoint on the `int childNumber = ` line (F9) and hit F5. Are you sure `GridView1` is not null?

Comment: Right now when I `Debugg` the `for loop` goes through all the x:Names in `Main.xaml` but the x:name i want to reach is inside the `TemplateGrid.xaml`(The UserControl template).

Comment: Does that `GridView1` contain the "StatusColor" Rectangle you want? (first parameter to your FindChildControl method - in a previous version I had used "this") And if not found, then you *will* get a `null` - which may lead to an exception later on if you do not test for that.

Comment: As you can se in my question, the `GridView` contains a `DataTemplate` of my in this case `UserControl` and that `Template` is named `TemplateGrid`, witch contains the `Rectangle` named `StatusColor`.

Comment: Did you use the correct parameter in your method call? In a previous version I had "this" instead of "GridView1"

Comment: Oh im so sorry i didn't se that, i will try directly :) Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: No, it's still throwing the same exception... :(